# Extracting fields from a vsftpd log line using bash

Tags: bash, awk

Hi i am trying to extract the date and other fields using a bash script but getting stuck.

`Mon Mar 4 22:24:05 2019 [pid 18349] [myuser] OK UPLOAD: Client ::ffff:127.0.0.1, /path/to/file, 3746080 bytes, 496.03Kbyte/sec`

I am able to fetch the following values

````
date = ```echo $log | awk '{print $3 FS $2 FS $5}'```
time = `echo $log | awk '{print $4}'`
action = `echo $log | awk '{print $9 FS $10}'`
size = `echo $log | awk '{print $14}'`
````

However I am having trouble extracting `ip` and `username`.

```
for ip `echo $log | awk '{print $12}'`
```

gives `::ffff:127.0.0.1,` how to extract ip `127.0.0.1` from this? Can anyone help? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a little improvement of your own code:

```
echo $log | awk '{gsub(/[^0-9.]/,"",$12);print $12}'
127.0.0.1
echo $log | awk '{gsub(/[\[\]]/,"",$8);print $8}'
myuser
```

And it's better use them like this:

```
ip=$(echo $log | awk '{gsub(/[^0-9.]/,"",$12);print $12}')
username=$(echo $log | awk '{gsub(/[\[\]]/,"",$8);print $8}')
```